# Oracle.ManagedDataAccess blows up on DbFunctions.CreateDate

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I have an EF query where I need to get the first day of the month in an Entity collection of DateTime.  This is using Linq to Entities (if it were Linq to Objects, I'd just instantiate a new DateTime).  This is basically the code I'm using:

```cs
dbContext.Calendar
    .Select(date => DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1, 0, 0, 0))
    .ToList();
```

This results in the following error: `ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0`

Looking at the data coming in, though, the closest thing I can see to a year of 0 is 2000, but it happens even if I limit it to a non-2000 year.

Also, `dbContext.Calendar.ToList();` works just fine, but it doesn't get me the first of the month.

Is this a known bug?  Is there a better way to find the first of the month?  Is there a better way to instantiate DateTimes in Linq to Entities for an Oracle DB?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I always hate it when the answer is staring me right in the face and I miss it OVER AND OVER AGAIN.  In this case, the solution was `AsEnumerable()`.  After that, you're using Linq to Objects, not Linq to Entities, so you can instantiate a DateTime like usual.

```cs
dbContext.Calendar
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(date => new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1))
    .ToList();
```